# Mover un archivo Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb, net

estoy tratando de mover un archivo dentro del Servidor. Tengo esto, pero no esta funcionando del todo bien. No encuentra la ruta correcta.

```
Dim Origen As String = "/images/foto.jpg"
Dim Destino As String = "/images/tarjetas/foto.jpg"
File.Move(Origen, Destino)
```

Comment: entiendo que `/images` no cuelga directamente del raiz. Debes o bien poner la ruta completa, o usar rutas relativas usando por ejemplo `../images/foto.jpg`

Comment: Muestra el error para ayudarte mejor, presumo que son las rutas. Intenta así: @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt"

Answer (score 0):

El Error Puede estar en que si no existe la carpeta de destino puede que no lo haga por error de existencia...
Prueba con lo siguiente que seguramente te de resultados:

```html
On Error Resume Next
Dim Origen As String = "/images/foto.jpg"
Dim Destino As String = "/images/tarjetas/foto.jpg"
MkDir("/images/tarjetas")
File.Move(Origen, Destino)
```

Answer (score 0):

El Código Que Te Indicaban es Para VB6 No Para .NET , Para .NET las Referencias a las Funciones Están en FileIO Que es el Acceso Que Se le Ha Dado en Esta Versión.
Puede Que Con el Otro Código No Estes Llamando Correctamente a los Puntos de las Funciones Que Hacen las Operaciones y Cómo Tienes la Detección de Errores No Ves Que Puede Estar Pasando, espero que esto te lo solucione. Saludos.

```html
On Error Resume Next
Dim Origen As String = "/images/foto.jpg"
Dim Destino As String = "/images/tarjetas/foto.jpg"
FileIO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("/images/tarjetas")
FileIO.FileSystem.MoveFile(Origen, Destino)
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Class Test
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim path As String = "c:\temp\MyTest.txt"
    Dim path2 As String = "c:\temp2\MyTest.txt"

    Try

        If Not File.Exists(path) Then

            Using fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)
            End Using
        End If

        If File.Exists(path2) Then File.Delete(path2)
        File.Move(path, path2)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} was moved to {1}.", path, path2)

        If File.Exists(path) Then
            Console.WriteLine("The original file still exists, which is unexpected.")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("The original file no longer exists, which is expected.")
        End If

    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```